# Let 3-COL-$K_4$-FREE be the decision problem that asks if a graph that doesn't contain $K_4$ admits a 3-coloring. Show that the problem is NP-complete

Tags: np-complete, colorings, polynomial-time-reductions

I'm kind of struggling with this excercise. The obvious thing to try is to show that **3-COL** $\leq_p$ **3-COL-$K_4$-FREE**
($\leq_p$ stands for polynomial reduction). It is clear that **3-COL-$K_4$-FREE** is in $NP$.

The first thing that comes to mind then is to take the trivial reduction that maps a graph $G$ to itself, but this doesn't work because a graph which contains $K_4$ is not a valid instance of **3-COL-$K_4$-FREE**. So, i'm looking for a polynomial reduction that maps a graph $G$ to some other $G'$ such that it gets rid of every $K_4$ in $G$ while preserving the coloring in both ways (i.e, a reduction $r$ such that $G$ is a positive instance of **3-COL** $\iff$ $r(G)$ is a positive instance of **3-COL-$K_4$-FREE**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible reduction $f$ from $3\text{-COL}$.
Let $H$ be any fixed graph that does not contain $K_4$ and is not $3$-colorable (e.g., $H=(\{1,2,3,4,5\}, \{(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,5), (4,5)\})$). Given an instance $G$ of $3\text{-COL}$ $f(G)$, define $f$ as follows:
$$
f(G) = \begin{cases}
H & \text{ if $G$ contains $K_4$}; \\
G & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

The function $f(G)$ is computable in polynomial-time since you can simply inspect all sets of $4$ vertices from $G=(V,E)$ in time $O(|V|^4)$.

To see that the reduction is correct, notice that if $G$ contains $K_4$ then $G \not\in 3\text{-COL}$ and $f(G) = H \not\in 3\text{-COL-}K_4\text{-FREE}$.
Otherwise $G \in 3\text{-COL} \iff f(G) = G \in 3\text{-COL-}K_4\text{-FREE}$.